# passing structs to functions as void pointers

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm trying to pass a pointer of a struct to a function but when I try to access the struct the last variable inside the struct is missing 1 byte off its memory address causing anything using that variable to segfault.

```
typedef struct
{
  pthread_t tID;
  int tType;
}sThread;

sThread threads[MAX_THREADS];

typedef struct
{
  int tID;
  int sock;
  int arg_count;
  char *from_p, **arg_p;
}command_struct;

pthread_t Thread_Start(void *function, void *param)
{
  pthread_t tHandle;

  pthread_create(&tHandle, NULL, function, (void*)param);

  return tHandle;
}

void cmd_test(int sock, char *from_p, char **arg_p, int arg_count)
{ 
  if(thread_check(1))
  {
    send_line(sock, "%s :test thread already running", from_p);
    return;
  }

  command_struct test;

  test.tID = thread_add(1);
  test.arg_count = arg_count;
  test.arg_p = arg_p;

  threads[test.tID].tID = Thread_Start(test_cmd, &test);
}

void *test_cmd(void *param)
{ 
  command_struct test = *((command_struct *)param);

  int i = 0;

  for(i = 1; i < test.arg_count; i++)
  {
    printf("%s", test.arg_p[i]);
  }

  thread_clear(test.tID);
  return NULL;
}
```

What is happening is inside cmd_test (the function to spawn the thread) the structure is initialized correctly and all variables are correct.

```
$1 = {tID = 0, sock = 5, arg_count = 5, from_p = 0xbffff254 "test", arg_p = 0xbfffec48}
```

But from withing test_cmd which is inside a running thread the structre is missing 1 byte off arg_p's address resulting in:

```
$1 = {tID = 0, sock = 5, arg_count = 5, from_p = 0xbffff254 "test", arg_p = 0xffec48}
```

If I add a useless variable to the end of my command_struct arg_p's address then becomes correct and the last variable in the command_struct is missing 1 byte off it's memory address.

Comment: Sometimes you are using the name `argp`, and sometimes `arg`. Is this just a mistake trying to summarize the problem, or is it actually called `argp` in the debugger and `arg` in the code? I worry that you're debugging something different than you think, or you're including the wrong header file. One way to solve this, which is also helpful for posting questions on StackOverflow, is to try to trim your program down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Doing so might help you find it; if not, you can post the complete program here, which makes it much easier to find the problem.

Comment: this is just a summary. sorry about that. let me try to trim down the example to semi real code

Comment: Any reason why you're using a void pointer and not a command_struct pointer?

Comment: in the real code it actually spawns "test_cmd" in a thread and keeps tracks of thread ids and such in another struct. i took it out for simplicity. i call the function via:   pthread_create(&tHandle, NULL, function, (void*)param);  function being the memory address of the function and param being the memory address of the struct. i would post the real code but i doubt you guys would want to read through my entire threading platform to keep track of threads when i can simply simplify the problem down.

Comment: No segfault here (gcc 4.6.2). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Have you tried it with a simple wrapper `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { cmd(argv, argc); return 0; }`?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: tried to clarify my problem more with more code on my end and an explanation of whats happening including gdb logs. hopefully that can help you and others out better. also the project is a bit to complex to simply create a wrapper for it unfortunately.

Comment: nobody has said this yet - fundamentally what you are doing should work.

Comment: I don't expect that to cause it, but the first argument to `Thread_Start` should be `void *(*function)(void*)`.

Comment: @pm100: interesting. id hate to do it but i could always just pad the end of the struct with a 1-2 byte variable that does nothing but thats a pretty hack job way of fixing this.

Comment: @bobmoch Michael Burr has the right answer. I would like to point out that you didn't actually get an answer to your question until you posted the real code that was failing. Posting example code that you haven't actually tried is generally not a good way to solve a problem; because you assumed the problem was in a different place than it was, you didn't show the relevant detail in your original question. Real code, that actually demonstrates the problem, goes much further. It's even better if you provide a complete example, that someone can compile and run to reproduce the problem themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a local variable to your thread - by the time the thread accesses it, the memory has been reused for something else.

Try this:

```
void cmd_test(int sock, char *from_p, char **arg_p, int arg_count)
{ 
    if(thread_check(1))
    {
        send_line(sock, "%s :test thread already running", from_p);
        return;
    }

    // === begin modified code in cmd_test():
    command_struct* test = malloc(sizeof(command_struct));

    test->tID = thread_add(1);
    test->arg_count = arg_count;
    test->arg_p = arg_p;

    threads[test.tID].tID = Thread_Start(test_cmd, test);
    // === end modified code
}

void *test_cmd(void *param)
{ 
    command_struct test = *((command_struct *)param);
    free(param);    // <-- new line of code

    // remainder is the same...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks this fixed one problem but brought upon another. i can pass integers through the struct but when i try to pass a pointer or a pointer to a pointer the result is always blank in the thread. (in gdb before the thread is launched it looks like `$1 = {tID = 0, str = 0xbffff096 "1.2", throt = 90, p = 10, ti = 10}` but i start the thread it looks looks like `$2 = {tID = 0, str = 0xbffff096 "", throt = 90, p = 10, ti = 10}` inside the thread using your modified code. (it fixed the original memory problem.)

Comment: never mind i managed to work around it by defining str as as `char str[18];` rather then `char *str` then using sprintf to put my arg_p variable inside of it. just a question did it do that because i didnt malloc room for the `char *str;` ?